# Load a few images only - responsiveslides.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-slides

I am using the reponsiveslide.js jquery plugin. The problem is the slideshow has contains about 30 images. The page doesn't load properly until ALL of these images are loaded making the rendering of the page very strange/delayed.

Is there a way to only load the first couple of slides first and then the rest after the page has loaded?

Many thanks

Comment: What you're looking for is called `lazy loading`. It seems that there were plans to implement it, but I'm not sure if they went through with it: https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js/issues/141

Comment: Any jQuery I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Check out the jQuery lazyload plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload